# Attempt to create nested for loops generating missing arguments error

Tags: tcl

Am attempting to teach myself to program using Tcl. (I want to become more familiar with the language to understand someone else's code - SCID chess)
The task i've set myself to motivate my learing of Tcl is to solve the 8 queens problem.
My approach to creating a program is to sucessively 'prototype' a solution.
So.
I'm up to nesting a for loop holding the q pos on row 2 
   inside the for loop holding the q pos on row 1

Here is my code

```
set allowd 1
set notallowd 0

for {set r1p 1} {$r1p <= 8} {incr r1p } {
    puts "1st row q placed at $r1p" 
    ;# re-initialize r2 'free for q placemnt' array after every change of r1 q pos:
    for {set i 1 } {$i <= 8} {incr i} { set r2($i) $allowd    }

    for { set r2($r1p) $notallowd ; set r2([eval $r1p-1]) $notallowd ;
           set r2([eval $r1p+1]) $notallowd ; set r2p 1}   {$r2p <= 8} {
         incr r2p ;# end of 'next' arg of r2 forloop
        }
        ;# commnd arg of r2 forloop placed below: 
        {puts "2nd row q placed at $r2p"    
    }
}
```

My problem is that when i run the code the interpreter is aborting with the fatal error:
"wrong #args should be for start test next command.

I've gone over my code a few times and can't see that i've missed any of the for loop arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The carriage return before the command in the last for loop is what's getting you. From the [first syntax rule on the Tcl man page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M6), "Semi-colons and newlines are command separators unless quoted as described below." BTW, your eval's should be expr's.

This works for me:

```
set allowd 1
set notallowd 0

for {set r1p 1} {$r1p <= 8} {incr r1p } {
    puts "1st row q placed at $r1p" 
    ;# re-initialize r2 'free for q placemnt' array after every change of r1 q pos:
    for {set i 1 } {$i <= 8} {incr i} { set r2($i) $allowd    }

    for { set r2($r1p) $notallowd ; set r2([expr $r1p-1]) $notallowd ;
        set r2([expr $r1p+1]) $notallowd ; set r2p 1}   {$r2p <= 8} {
        incr r2p ;# end of 'next' arg of r2 forloop
    } {
        # commnd arg of r2 forloop placed below: 
        puts "2nd row q placed at $r2p"    
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks very much! Will this work as an aide memoire for me not to fall down the same type of error again:  if one runs out of space and arguments remain to be typed for a function then an opening brace for the next argument must be placed at the end of the line , to give warning (so to say) to the interpreter that 'more is to follow' ?

Comment: It's not that the interpreter changes how it parses the command, it's that the arg's body happens to contain a newline. BTW, you can also continue a command by adding "\" at the end of the line.

Comment: To be exact, the Tcl interpreter (and also the bytecode compiler, of course) *always* parses *everything* in *exactly the same way*. Really. There aren't any special syntaxes that aren't listed on the main Tcl language manual page.